# Why must I include a semicolon when putting a label at the end of a function?

Tags: c, label, goto

Simple function with a `goto` error handler:

```
void checkFile(char *name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(name, "r");
    if(NULL == fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", name);
        goto end;
    }

    // use fp...

    fclose(fp);
    end:
    ;
}
```

Notice, if I remove the useless semicolon after `end:` the function fails to compile.

On GCC:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
   16 | }
```

On MSVC:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
```

So, I understand that C standard does say that the destination of the `goto` keyword expects a statement in § 6.8.6.1 p 2:

> A goto statement causes an unconditional jump to the **statement prefixed** by the named label in the enclosing function

However, the error exists just because the label exists; if I remove the `goto` keyword, the label itself is still treated as an error and won't compile. I read the standard's section on "Labeled statements" (§ 6.8.1) but still didn't find anything that explained this odd constraint.

Comment: So it expects a statement. `;` is an empty statement. Without it there is no statement.

Comment: `end: {}` is also a statement, no semicolon needed :-)

Comment: Re “So, I understand that C standard does say that the destination of the goto keyword expects a statement”: So what is your question? Since you know a `goto` goes to a statement prefixed by a label, why are you surprised a label must have a statement?

Comment: https://i2.paste.pics/11f5fb945ae20acd1233dc912f5e8974.png

Comment: Ugh. Let me guess:  you have some restrictive code standard that prevents you from simply doing a `return` immediately upon failure and instead you have to use a `goto`.  Whoever wrote that shortsighted requirement completely failed to understand why you bother to write code standards in the first place:  make code consistently more readable.  Forcing the use of a `goto` fails that test.  It's like an Olympic diver doing a cannonball in the competition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C a label may be placed before a statement. So if there is no statement you can place a null statement.

From the C Standard (6.8.1 Labeled statements)

```
labeled-statement:
    identifier : statement
    case constant-expression : statement
    default : statement
```

And (6.8.3 Expression and null statements)

```
expression-statement:
    expressionopt ;
```

> 3 A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no
> operations.

Opposite to C in C++ declarations are also statements. So in C++ you may place a label before a declaration.

Here are demonstrative programs.

**C program.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    goto End;
    
    End:;
    const char *bye = "Bye";
    
    puts( bye );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Bye
```

**C++ program**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    goto End;
    
    End:
    const char *bye = "Bye";
    
    std::cout <<  bye << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Bye
```

Pay attention to that in the C program after the label there is placed a null statement

```
End:;
```

Without it the compiler will issue an error.